# Create column based on multiple conditions in r

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame with 3 columns: individual ID, trip (which is sequenced by ID), and forage (yes or no):

```
example <- data.frame(IDs = c(rep("A",30),rep("B",30)), 
                  timestamp = seq(c(ISOdate(2016,10,01)), by = "day", length.out = 60),
                  trip = c(rep("1",15),rep("2",15)), 
                  forage = c(rep("Yes",3),rep("No",5),rep("Yes",3),rep("No",4),rep("Yes",7),rep("No",8)))
```

I want to create two separate columns that will list foraging events for each observation. In the first column, I want to number each observation with foraging = "yes" within ID and trip (so, each trip within individual will have x number of foraging events, starting over again with "1" for the next trip within individual). This column would look like:

```
example$forageEvent1 <- c(rep(1,3),rep("NA",5),rep(2,3),rep("NA",4),rep(1,7),rep("NA",8),rep(1,3),rep("NA",5),rep(2,3),rep("NA",4),rep(1,7),rep("NA",8))
```

The second column will number the foraging events by ID only:

```
example$forageEvent2 <- c(rep(1,3),rep("NA",5),rep(2,3),rep("NA",4),rep(3,7),rep("NA",8),rep(1,3),rep("NA",5),rep(2,3),rep("NA",4),rep(3,7),rep("NA",8))
```

I can subset/pipe down to individual and trip & have tried ifelse(), but have no idea how to write a code that will create a sequence of events. Thanks all.

EDIT: the code below, edited from a comment, gets close. However, it prints starting with "Forage0" instead of "Forage1".

```
library(dplyr)
Test_example <- example %>%
  group_by(IDs) %>%
  mutate(
  ForagebyID = case_when(
   forage == "Yes" ~ "Forage",
   forage == "No" ~"NonForage"),
  rleid = cumsum(ForagebyID != lag(ForagebyID, 1, default = "NA")), 
 ForagebyID = case_when(
  ForagebyID == "Forage" ~ paste0(ForagebyID, rleid %/% 2),
  TRUE ~ "NonForage"),
rleid = NULL
)
```

Comment: sessionInfo()R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: Wait, so you actually want duplicate rows? The current version of `example` for instance will have rows 1-3 completely duplicated.

Comment: Very similar concept here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408321/add-a-new-column-based-on-data-in-between-zeroes/45408517

Comment: @Kim Well, there are timestamps in another column but I left them out of the example to make it simpler. I can add them back in.

Comment: Well @thelatemail almost got me there with this, but it starts with "Forage0" instead of "Forage1": `Test_example <- example %>%
  group_by(IDs) %>%
  mutate(
    ForagebyID = case_when(
     forage == "Yes" ~ "Forage",
     forage == "No" ~"NonForage"),
    rleid = cumsum(ForagebyID != lag(ForagebyID, 1, default = "NA")), 
    ForagebyID = case_when(
      ForagebyID == "Forage" ~ paste0(ForagebyID, rleid %/% 2),
      TRUE ~ "NonForage"),
    rleid = NULL
  )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do what you want:

```
library(dplyr)

example <- data.frame(IDs = c(rep("A",30),rep("B",30)), 
                      timestamp = seq(c(ISOdate(2016,10,01)), by = "day", length.out = 60),
                      trip = c(rep("1",15),rep("2",15)), 
                      forage = c(rep("Yes",3),rep("No",5),rep("Yes",3),rep("No",4),rep("Yes",7),rep("No",8)))

Test_example <- example %>%
  arrange(IDs, timestamp) %>%
  group_by(IDs, trip) %>%
  mutate(forageEvent1 = case_when(forage == "No" ~ 0,
                                  TRUE ~ cumsum(forage != lag(forage, default = 1)) %/% 2 + 1)) %>%
  group_by(IDs) %>%
  mutate(forageEvent2 = case_when(forage == "No" ~ 0,
                                  TRUE ~ cumsum(forage != lag(forage, default = 1)) %/% 2 + 1))
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!