# How to count and identify equivalent groups within a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a simple dataframe made of 0's and 1's

```
library(dplyr)      
d <- data.frame(x=c(0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,1))
```

I want each group of 1's to be identified by a unique id:

```
   x id
1  0  0
2  0  0
3  1  1
4  1  1
5  0  0
6  1  2
7  1  2
8  1  2
9  0  0
10 0  0
11 1  3
```

It could be solved using a simple loop, which I want to avoid.
I have tried with group_indice (dplyr), na.locf (zoo) and cumsum and so far don't see a way through.

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408321/add-a-new-column-based-on-data-in-between-zeroes/45408517 which would suggest - `d$id <- 0; d$id[d$x==1] <- as.numeric(factor(cumsum(d$x==0)[d$x==1]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with `cumsum` and `diff`

```
G1 = cumsum(c(d$x[1] == 1, diff(d$x) == 1))
d$id = ifelse(d$x==1, G1, 0)
d
   x id
1  0  0
2  0  0
3  1  1
4  1  1
5  0  0
6  1  2
7  1  2
8  1  2
9  0  0
10 0  0
11 1  3
```

you need the `d$x[1] == 1` part in case the first element of x is a 1.

Answer (score 0):

A simple base method using `rle`:

```
r <- rle(d$x)
r$values[r$values == 1] <- seq_len(sum(r$values == 1))
d$id <- rep(r$values,times = r$lengths)
```